# CLion CMake not working when linking to library but visual studio does

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clion

My problem right now is that when using CLion and using the following cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(my_library)

# C++ version
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Create Library
add_library(
    my_library

    public/testlib/config.h
    public/testlib/config.cpp
)

target_include_directories(
    my_library
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/private
)

# Make Test File
add_executable(lib_test testing/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib_test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public)
target_link_libraries(lib_test PUBLIC my_library)
```

It compiles perfectly fine using visual studio with clang++ and cmake, and the lib_test.exe works! Unfortunately when I do this in CLion (clang++ and cmake) I get multiple 'lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: __cdecl ' errors for every time I use the library in the main.cpp file. I was able to fix this by specifying the library to be an OBJECT library like this:

```
add_library(
    my_library
    OBJECT

    public/testlib/config.h
    public/testlib/config.cpp
)
```

And then it works perfectly fine in CLion.
My question is why? Does visual studio automatically do this? Or is it something else?

Thank you very much in advance :)

EDIT:
I'd like to export a statically linked library.

config.h File:

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace TestLib
{
    struct Config
    {
        const char* name;
        int width;
        int height;

        Config();
    };
}
```

config.cpp File:

```cpp
#include <testlib/config.h>

using namespace TestLib;

Config::Config()
{
    this->name = nullptr;
    this->width = 0;
    this->height = 0;
}
```

main.cpp File:

```cpp
#include <testlib/config.h>

using namespace TestLib;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Config config;
    config.name = "haha yes";
    config.width = 1280;
    config.height = 720;

    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: __cdecl TestLib::Config::Config(void)
>>> referenced by D:\testlib\testing\main.cpp:7
>>>               CMakeFiles/lib_test.dir/testing/main.cpp.obj:(main)

clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You definitely need to be more specific about your code (c++ one) and the error messages you got. Please, prepare [mcve] which represents your problem.

Comment: Alright, added the main.cpp file contents and error message!

Comment: Well, know we can see your exact `Main.cpp` file. What about other files? Instead of note `config is just a simple struct...` just show that header and sources for the library. Also, instead of `all the .h and .cpp files... (for example ...` just show what you **actually** have in `CMakeLists.txt`. Do not try to generalize your question post from the beginning. Instead, show the **exact code** you have. When later your problem will become clear (for you or for others), the question could be edited for reflect generalized problem.

Comment: Ok done, sorry for being so stupid in the beginning lol. Anyway, I've placed the exact code I have there :)

Comment: Much better now. Shouldn't `using namespace TestLib;` be in your `main.cpp` too? Otherwise, compiler would be unable for understand `Config` as `TestLib::Config`.

Comment: BTW, if `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public` contains header files only for your library, then `target_include_directories(lib_test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public)` is not needed: your executable will get this include directory automatically, because it links with the library.

Comment: Oh I dont understand why the using namespace TestLib didn't copy over. I am doing that in my main.cpp though

Comment: [mcve] should only focus on a single problem. I suspect that executable is not relevant here at all. Most likely `add_library` does not do what you think it does. It is not clear what you expect it to do, but it may produce static and / or shared library depending on the value of `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` envar. However your library code may not work as shared library because it does not export anything. It could be a kind of situation where you are linking with static library on VS but with empty dynamic library in clion. So the first thing here is to check build artifact produced by `add_library`.

Comment: And ensure that it does contain definition of `TestLib::Config::Config` as intended. It would be a good idea to specify explicitly kind of library you want to build.

Comment: @user7860670: Now the question post focuses on a single problem. If the library is created incorrectly, then linking a small executable is a good way to detect that. However, exporting symbols for shared libraries on windows is the very thing I would think of. It could be useful to see **complete verbose output** of building the library and the executable.